# C++ Write Macro for finding an integer type given another integer type

Tags: c++, templates, boost, macros, integer

I have a function which looks like this:

```cpp
template<class T, class E, class U = T> T function(T input1, E input2) {
    // implementation here
}
```

Instead of the above declaration, I want the default for `U` to be a macro which takes `T` for input. More specifically, I want the default for `U` to be `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` if `T` is `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int`, and I want the default for `U` to be an integer with double the precision of `T` for fixed precision `T`.

I know the second part can be accomplished with:

```cpp
U = boost::uint_t<2 * std::numeric_limits<T>::digits>::fast
```

How do I check for `T` being a `cpp_int` (or any other arbitrary precision integer within std and boost), and put everything together in a macro?

Edit:

I found that testing for arbitrary precision can be done through:

```
std::numeric_limits<T>::is_bounded
```

I still do not know how to combine these 2 tests into 1 macro.

Comment: You could write an overload taking `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int`. That way the compiler will just select that one over the template.

Comment: The overload will require template partial specialization due to class E, so that doesnt work for me.

Comment: No, you don't have to specialize, just write another function without T or U, and use `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` in their place.

Comment: That could work. I'm using this function inside several other templated functions, so I will still need to test if the inputs to those templates are cpp_int/arbitrary precision, and I don't know how to do that. But I will be able to avoid writing a macro.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want macros for this?

Comment: @TedLyngmo the specific function im writing is a pow_mod function and the purpose of class U is to account for overflows. Because of the nature of the function and the fact that it will be called many times, i want as much of the overhead to be done at compile time. The answer I found works decently, and I did it without too many annoying variadic macros or things like that.

Comment: I see. With templates you can make pretty sure to not get uncessary runtime overhead by using type traits.though. I'd stay away from macros unless you need things that can't be solved otherwise (which isn't much in C++20).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defined a custom boost multiprecision int using a macro, and hid the function backends behind another function which checks types. U is void so that the user has the option of customizing it. If T is fixed precision, the function calls the macro, otherwise passes cpp_int as a template argument. The type deduction of the custom boost int is done at compile time and the if statements are probably evaluated at compile time as well.

```
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

#ifndef BOOST_UINT
#define BOOST_UINT(bit_count) boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_backend<bit_count, bit_count, boost::multiprecision::unsigned_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void>>
#endif

template<class T, class E, class U = void> T function(T input1, E input2) {
    if(std::is_same<U, void>::value) {
        if(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_bounded) {
            return function_backend<T, E, BOOST_UINT( ((std::numeric_limits<T>::digits + 1) >> 1) << 2)>(input1, input2);
        } else {
            return function_backend<T, E, cpp_int>(input1, input2);
        }
    } else {
        return function_backend<T, E, U>(input, input2);
    }
}

template<class T, class E, class U> T function_backend(T input1, E input2);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to use `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` if the double size of `T` is larger than an `int64_t`.

Idea:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

// type trait to get an int of the requested size
template<size_t S>
struct int_size {
    using type = std::conditional_t<S==1, int8_t,
                     std::conditional_t<S==2, int16_t,
                         std::conditional_t<S==4, int32_t,
                             std::conditional_t<S==8, int64_t,
                                                boost::multiprecision::cpp_int>>>>;
};

template<size_t S>
using int_size_t = int_size<S>::type;
```

Then make `U` double the size of `T` or `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` if it's larger than an `int64_t`:

```
template<class T, class E, class U = int_size_t<sizeof(T) * 2>> 
T function(T input1, E input2) {
    // implementation here
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5v3aEqnrb)

Comment: This is an interesting answer, I did not know about conditionals so I have to learn more about them

Comment: @dancxviii [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) is a really neat little class template + a specialization. Look at the "_possible implementation_" of `std::conditional`. Really simple, but it helps a lot.